# Multiple UV maps in one final image?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, texture-baking

Still fairly new to Blender so apologies if this comes across as 'noobish'!

Ok, so I have built a simple object in Blender (using 2.76) and I'm using Cycles Render.  It has 5 different textures, 2 of which are emissions without a texture.

I have assigned each texture it's own UV map - I usually give the UV maps the same name as the texture but appended with _UV.

I have unwrapped each texture onto it's corresponding image, scaling and rotating islands as necessary to give the best look.

Now when I want to bake the final texture (this is a one-piece object) and I select all the islands, there are lots of overlaps and parts outside of the texture boundary.

If I try to move or scale the textures get messed up.

If I try to use the Pack Islands feature, the textures get REALLY messed up!

I know this is probably a simple step I am missing, but this is the first thing I have found where I literally cannot find a way past it.  It's starting to drive me to distraction!

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I forgot to add, what I am trying to achieve is to get all of the islands packed into the final image, without losing the scaling or the rotations that I already set in earlier steps :)